# WP7 How to remove a pivot item when there are controls inside it

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivotitem

I used to do that to remove a pivot Item : nameOfThePivot.Items.remove(nameOfthePivotItem).

But then I changed my pivot Item to :

```
    <controls:PivotItem x:Name="DistributionPivot"  >
        <controls:PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="distribution" />
        </controls:PivotItem.Header>
```

and now it is impossible to remove this item : I've got the error : ArgumentException is unhandled

It is apparently a known bug, but I can't find how to fix it. Do you have another idea to hide a pivotItem.

Thank you

Comment: What does your `AgumentException` tell you?

Comment: Where abouts are you calling the Pivot.Items.Remove method? If you are calling from one of the event handlers associated with any controls that are on that particular pivotitem then you are likely to receive the exception you are getting. If you try removing one pivot item from another pivot item then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: either have your items as a bound collection and update the underlying collection or generate the items in code and then add and remove them.

It's not possible to remove an item created in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with PivotItems I have created in XAML. I created these extension methods as a helper.

```
public static class PivotFeatureSwitchHelper
    {
        public static bool RemovePivotItemIfExistsByHeaderName(this Pivot p, string headerKey)
        {
            var item = FindPivotItemWithHeaderName(p, headerKey);
            return item != null && p.Items.Remove(item);
        }


        public static PivotItem FindPivotItemWithHeaderName(this Pivot p, string name)
        {
            return (PivotItem)p.Items.FirstOrDefault(mem => name.Equals( (string)(((PivotItem)mem).Header), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Since you've customized each header (instead of the Pivot's HeaderTemplate), you should cast to a TextBlock and get the Text property, instead of casting to the string. Since you're usage is more specific to your app, I'm going to leave the example as is since it'll be more useful for others who have a similar issue.